# LWC initializing Modal/popup when Record Page loads

Tags: lightning-web-components, pagereference, modal

I created a LWC Modal/Popup component, a simple modal window to display some text. This modal window has OK and Close buttons.

To test this modal/popoup I added a button to call it in the Record Page in Lightning App Builder and it works as expected. The modal/popup gets displayed and Record page cannot be navigated until the modal/popup is closed.

Now I would like to know if there is a way to add this modal/popup to the initialization of Record Page, so whenever and Account is opened that this modal/popup gets displayed first.
And if the user clicks to close the modal/popup, the whole Record page should close.

Kind Regards,
Safaas

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the code that trigger the modal in a lifecycle hook : such as [connectedCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_lifecycle_hooks)

So your modal will show up when the user load the page for example.